# asp:Literal control null in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I've a user control which contains asp:Literal.

```
<div>
     <asp:Literal id="MenuContainer" runat="server" />
</div>
```

There is a method in code-behind page which initializes the control:

```
internal void Setup(MyBusinessObject obj)
{
    MenuObject menu = MenuHelper.GetMenu(obj.State);

    if(obj == null)
        MenuContainer.Visible = false;

    //other code
}
```

In the page where the control is used I call **Setup** method of control in **LoadComplete** event handler (I was first calling it in *Load* event). Irrespective of *MyBusinessObject* being null or not null, when I access *Literal* on user-control I get error:

```
Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
```

What is the reason and what is the remedy for this?

Comment: It IS working fine for me tho. There may be some other problem. Try compiling the whole website. And by the way, are you able to access other controls in that usercontrol properly?

Comment: Actually this is the only control in the user-contorl

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It was very simple. I was adding things in web.config's controls section as was suggested by [Rick Sthral](http://www.west-wind.com/weblog) in one of his post ( :( for got about the post, you will have to search on his page).

It was nicely allowing me to add controls without putting **@ Register** tag but the downside was that child controls on my controls were shown as null! so I simply put **@ Register** directive in my pages and it worked.

Comment: +1, thanks! Though can anyone explain this nonsensical solution?  Isn't the web.config shortcut supposed to remove the need for littering the page markup with Register directives?  Why even bother if we have to put it there anyway to prevent strange, hair-pulling-out errors like this?  Okay, </rant>.

Comment: @Yadyn that's what I'm not able to understand. I've put comment on Rick's blog but haven't got any reply.

Answer (score 5):

It depends on exactly *how* you're including the controls in your web.config. It will not work if you try to include all of the controls in a namespace (although the designer will correctly show you the list of your controls):

```
<add tagPrefix="prefix" namespace="example.ui.controls" assembly="example.ui" />
```

But if you add your control(s) individually and point to their physical location(s), it will work as you expect without having to include endless `@Register` directives.

```
<add tagPrefix="prefix" tagName="Message" src="~/Controls/Message.ascx" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, TheVillageIdiot, for posting the answer to your problem - I ran into exactly the same misunderstanding.

Adding controls via

```
<add tagPrefix="user" namespace="Frontend.Web.UserControlsAccount" assembly="Frontend.Web" />
```

in the web.config was not enough to actually use it! I tried it like this on a page:

```
<user:ucLoginMessages runat="server" ID="Msgs" />
```

... but this would lead to the phenomenon, that none of the controls inside the UserControl were initialized. Only adding

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControlsAccount/LoginMessages.ascx" TagPrefix="user" TagName="Messages" %>
```

to the top of the page solved the problem :-)

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure `MenuContainer` is the problem?  You are referencing `obj.State` in the first line of the `Setup` function.  If that `obj` is null you'll get that error.

Comment: Yes, It is the problem. if(obj == null) passes. MenuContainer.Visible throws exception.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the answer by [JerSchneid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891334/aspliteral-control-null-in-user-control/891370#891370), if obj is null, you'll get that error. So, try doing it like this -

```
internal void Setup(MyBusinessObject obj)
{
    if(obj == null)
        MenuContainer.Visible = false;
    else
        MenuObject menu = MenuHelper.GetMenu(obj.State);
}
```

EDIT: I know you are getting an error on that line, but just try doing it like this. Or, else, remove the whole code and just keep the `MenuContainer.Visible = false;` line.

Comment: Dear the obj is not null only the MenuContainer is null. That is why I'm puzzled.

Answer (score 0):

If `MenuContainer` is null, it probably has something to do with the time line of the page life cycle.  You're calling that function before `MenuContainer` is linked up.  Can you try calling `Setup` in the Page_Load function?

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted is the following:

```
internal void Setup(MyBusinessObject obj)
{    
    MenuObject menu = MenuHelper.GetMenu(obj.State);    

    if(obj == null)        
        MenuContainer.Visible = false;    //other code
}
```

- If obj is null, then dereferencing obj.State on the first line will throw a NullReferenceException
- If obj is not null, the line MenuContainer.Visible = false won't be executed.

So I don't think you're posting all the relevant code.

When you're having difficulty debugging this kind of thing, try stepping through the code with the debugger or adding some asserts to your code, which will help you to see exactly what's happening:

```
internal void Setup(MyBusinessObject obj)
{    
    Debug.Assert(obj != null);
    MenuObject menu = MenuHelper.GetMenu(obj.State);    

    Debug.Assert(MenuContainer != null);
    if(obj == null)        
        MenuContainer.Visible = false;    //other code
}
```